# How can I convert a comma seperated string with pipes to two different arrays?

Tags: php, arrays

How can I convert a comma seperated string with pipes to two different arrays?

```
$combo_string = 'blue|car, red|truck, green|boat, yellow|bike';
```

where I need:

```
$colors_array = 

Array (
[0] => blue
[1] => red
[2] => green
[3] => yellow
)
```

and

```
$vehicles_array = 

Array (
[0] => car
[1] => truck
[2] => boat
[3] => bike
)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would first break up the comma, then pipes. Show us some code of what you've tried.

Comment: I would recommend the `explode()` function.

Comment: I was asking how to do it. The code?...

Comment: @Sammy Sorry, we don't do the work here for you. You can try something and then we can help you.

Comment: i already tried explode, preg_match, and preg_match_all. I just don't know the correct way to do it.

Comment: @Sammy Your question doesn't mention that. You should read [Jon Skeet's guide](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx) on how to write a good question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$combo_array = explode(', ', $combo_string);

$colors_array = $vehicles_array = array();
foreach ($combo_array as $piece) {
   list($color, $vehicle) = explode('|', $piece);
   $colors_array[] = $color;
   $vehicles_array[] = $vehicle;
}
```

Comment: Can even do: `list($colors_array[], $vehicles_array[])` and cut the `foreach` loop down to one line and remove those temp variables.

Comment: how so? meaning? I am not a php pro

Comment: @nickb nice, I didn't even know you could do that.  In PHP 5.5 you will be able to use `foreach` with `list` as well, so it could even be a one-liner.

Comment: @nickb how so? do: list($colors_array[], $vehicles_array[]) and cut the foreach loop down to one line and remove those temp variables

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested the below, but it should be roughly correct:

```
$combo_string = 'blue|car, red|truck, green|boat, yellow|bike';

$initial_array = explode(", " $combo_string);

$vehicles_array = array();
$colors_array = array();

foreach ($combo_string as $item)
{
  $seperate_colour = explode("|", $item);

  $colors_array[] = $seperate_colour[0];
  $vehicles_array[] = $seperate_colour[1];

}
```